# Defining Visitors Inline in Modern C++ alternate take

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

I found a very interesting article on 
[Defining Visitors Inline in Modern C++](http://accu.org/index.php/articles/2021)

The solution proposed is quite complicated though.

I wonder if there is a simpler way of addressing this scenario?

*code and example added below to avoid needing to follow link.*

> Taking the example from the paper, given the following classes:
>
> ```
> struct Triangle; 
> struct Square;
>
> struct PolygonVisitor 
> { 
>   virtual ~PolygonVisitor() {}
>
>   virtual void visit(Triangle& tr) = 0;  
>   virtual void visit(Square& sq) = 0;
> };
>
> struct Polygon 
> { 
>   virtual void accept(PolygonVisitor& v) = 0;  
> };
>
> struct Triangle : Polygon 
> { 
>   void accept(PolygonVisitor& v) override 
>   {   
>     v.Visit(*this); 
>   }   
> };
>
> struct Square : Polygon 
> { 
>   void accept(PolygonVisitor& v) override 
>   {
>     v.Visit(*this); 
>   }   
> };
> ```
>
> An inline visitor is constructed and used to work out how many sides a
>   shape has:
>
> ```
> int CountSides(Polygon& p)
> { 
>   int sides = 0;
>
>   auto v = begin_visitor<PolygonVisitor>()
>     .on<Triangle>([&sides](Triangle& tr)
>     {
>        sides = 3;
>     })
>     .on<Square>([&sides](Square& sq)
>     {
>       sides = 4;
>     })
>     .end_visitor();
>
>   p.Accept(v);
>   return sides;
> }
> ```
>
> The inline visitor is defined as follows (code taken from
>   https://github.com/jbcoe/inline_visitor):
>
> ```
> template <typename T, typename F, typename BaseInnerVisitor, typename ArgsT>
> class ComposeVisitor
> {
>  public:
>   class InnerVisitor : public BaseInnerVisitor
>   {
>   public:
>     using BaseInnerVisitor::Visit;
>     typedef typename BaseInnerVisitor::VisitorInterface VisitorInterface;
>
>     InnerVisitor(ArgsT&& args)
>         : BaseInnerVisitor(std::move(args.second)), m_f(std::move(args.first))
>     {
>     }
>
>     void Visit(T& t) final
>     {
>       VisitImpl(t);
>     }
>
>   private:
>     template <typename F_ = F>
>     typename std::enable_if<
>         std::is_assignable<std::function<void(T&)>, F_>::value>::type
>     VisitImpl(T& t)
>     {
>       m_f(t);
>     }
>
>     template <typename F_ = F>
>     typename std::enable_if<std::is_assignable<
>         std::function<void(T&, VisitorInterface&)>, F_>::value>::type
>     VisitImpl(T& t)
>     {
>       m_f(t, *this);
>     }
>
>     F m_f;
>   };
>
>   ComposeVisitor(ArgsT&& args) : m_args(std::move(args))
>   {
>   }
>
>   template <typename Tadd, typename Fadd>
>   ComposeVisitor<Tadd, Fadd, InnerVisitor, std::pair<Fadd, ArgsT>>
>   on(Fadd&& f) &&
>   {
>     return ComposeVisitor<Tadd, Fadd, InnerVisitor, std::pair<Fadd, ArgsT>>(
>     std::make_pair(std::move(f), std::move(m_args)));
>   }
>
>   template <typename InnerVisitor_ = InnerVisitor>
>   typename std::enable_if<!std::is_abstract<InnerVisitor_>::value,
>                       InnerVisitor>::type
>   end_visitor() &&
>   {
>     return InnerVisitor(std::move(m_args));
>   }
>
>   ArgsT m_args;
> };
>
>
> template <typename TVisitorBase>
> class EmptyVisitor
> {
>  public:
>   class InnerVisitor : public TVisitorBase
>   {
>   public:
>     using TVisitorBase::Visit;
>     typedef TVisitorBase VisitorInterface;
>     InnerVisitor(std::nullptr_t)
>     {
>     }
>   };
>
>   template <typename Tadd, typename Fadd>
>   ComposeVisitor<Tadd, Fadd, InnerVisitor, std::pair<Fadd, std::nullptr_t>>
>   on(Fadd&& f) &&
>   {
>     return ComposeVisitor<Tadd, Fadd, InnerVisitor,
>                           std::pair<Fadd, std::nullptr_t>>(
>         std::make_pair(std::move(f), nullptr));
>   }
> };
>
>
> template <typename TVisitorBase>
> EmptyVisitor<TVisitorBase> begin_visitor()
> {
>   return EmptyVisitor<TVisitorBase>();
> }
> ```

Comment: Please add the relevant context to your question. Do not expect your audience to click on links here.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way of tackling this problem is inheriting from the abstract visitor ( PolygonVisitor in the example) a new class (InlineVisitor) that takes in its constructor a std::function for each abstract method it has to implement.

Each abstract method is implemented it in term of the std::function stored

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Triangle;
struct Square;
struct PolygonVisitor
{
    virtual ~PolygonVisitor() {}
    virtual void visit(Triangle& tr) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Square& sq) = 0;
};

struct Polygon {
    virtual void accept(PolygonVisitor& v) = 0;
};

struct Triangle : Polygon
{
    void accept(PolygonVisitor& v) override { v.visit(*this); } 
};

struct Square : Polygon
{
    void accept(PolygonVisitor& v) override { v.visit(*this); }
};


class InlineVisitor : public PolygonVisitor
{
    public:
        virtual void visit(Triangle& value) { triangleFx_(value); }
        virtual void visit(Square& value)   { squareFx_(value); }

        std::function<void(Triangle&)> triangleFx_;
        std::function<void(Square&)>   squareFx_;

        InlineVisitor(const std::function<void(Triangle&)> triangleFx, 
                      const std::function<void(Square&)>   squareFx)
            : triangleFx_(triangleFx)
            , squareFx_(squareFx) {}
};

int countSides(Polygon& p)
{
    int sides = 0;
    InlineVisitor countSidesVisitor([&sides](Triangle& tr) { sides = 3; }, 
                                    [&sides](Square& sq)   { sides = 4; });
    p.accept(countSidesVisitor);
    return sides;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Triangle t;
    Square s;
    std::cout << "sides of Triangle: " << countSides(t) << std::endl
              << "sides of Square: "   << countSides(s) << std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

The original implementation is more general while this retains the basic idea but is a simpler

Comment: I'd be curious to see how the generated assembler compares with a hand-written visitor.

The complexity we added to our design was all added to eliminate differences in generated assembler.